# How to get the value inside the accordian selected child

Tags: javascript, dojo

Why can't I get the value inside the accordian selected child.The code I used is below

```
function Alert1()
{     
    alert((dijit.byId("markup").selectedChildWidget.id).get('value'));
}

<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" id="editor1" data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){console.log('editor1 onChange handler: ' + arguments[0])}">
      <p>This instance is created from a div directly with default toolbar and plugins</p>    
</div>    

      <button onclick="Alert1();">Answer</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert((dijit.byId("markup").selectedChildWidget.id).get('value'));
```

Remove `id` in the above code.

```
var accordion = dijit.byId("markup");
var value = accordion.selectedChildWidget.get('value');
```